# Prove that $M_1^2\leq 2M_0M_2$, if $2M_1t≤2M_0+M_2t^2$

Tags: calculus, inequality, real-numbers

Let $0\leq M_1,M_2,M_3\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall \ t\in\mathbb{R}:\ 2M_1t≤2M_0+M_2t^2$. Prove that $M_1^2\leq 2M_0M_2$.

I tried assigning  different values to $t$, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: if the second-degree polynomial
$$ p(t) = M_2t^2-2M_1 t+2M_0 $$
is non-negative for every value of $t\in\mathbb{R}$, its discriminant has to be non-positive.

Notice that:

$$ M_2\cdot p(t) = (M_2 t-M_1)^2 + \color{red}{(2M_0 M_2-M_1^2)}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Since $2M_1 t \le 2M_0+M_2t^2$, then the function $f(t)=2M_0-2M_1t+M_2t^2$ is positive, i.e., $f$ does not change sign for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, which mean that the discriminant which is $4M_1^2 -8 M_0M_1 \le 0$ and this is equivalent to write $M_1 \le \sqrt{2}M_0M_2$.